# Creating drop-able menu when resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So I am trying to achieve a responsive website.

Here is my navigation so far (Window is maximized):

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that when the window is resized, a new tab will appear called menu. This will be a button which once clicked will show all the existing links I have.

I have two lists in two separate `div's`, ideally, when the window is resized, I would want the content from both `lists` to be view able in this new menu.

This is what it looks like when Chrome is resized to its lowest width:
[image]

As you can see, those links in the image (Stretches, posture etc), those should not be visible. They should dynamically show up once menu is clicked, which is another issue, clicking menu does nothing.

Everything I have can be found in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hudnybux/

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common use-case as im sure you can imagine. Googling it took me 5 seconds, [this](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-responsive-navigation-menu) was the first one that popped up. It seems simple and straight forward to follow.

As a general rule at stack overflow, try looking around a  bit before you ask a question...people will generally respond better to your answers. :)

Comment: If you view the fiddle, you can probably tell that I am using the same tutorial you have outlined, but not achieving the same result.